# Bash script that produces a variable with list of files, separated by newlines

Tags: bash

I am trying to save a list of files (actually, *.cpp files) into a variable, such that the list is separated by newlines. What I have come up with so far is:

```
VAR=''; for myfile in *.cpp; do VAR+=$myfile$'\n'; done
echo $VAR
```

However, the list of files does not contain any newlines, it's just a single whitespace. In fact, the white space processing seems completely off. For example, when typing

```
VAR=''; for myfile in *.cpp; do VAR+=$myfile$' o     o '; done
echo $VAR
```

All white space sequences get trimmed to a single white space. Nothing like happens if I emit strings immediately via echo. For example,

```
echo $'  hey\n\thow are you?'
```

looks just as expected.

How can it get the desired list of files in a variable?

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: wrt `I am trying to save a list of files (actually, *.cpp files) into a variable` - it's extremely unlikely that that's a better idea than saving the list into an array.

Comment: @Cyrus You are right. However, the accepted answer taught me something about shell variables as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the list of files does not contain any newlines, it's just a single whitespace

Is false. You are **printing** it separated with spaces, because word splitting expansion happens on unquoted variable expansion in `$VAR` and your `IFS` is default. As a rule of thumb, always quote variable expansions, ie. do `"$VAR"`.

> How can it get the desired list of files in a variable?

Your current method "works". It will fail on a edge cases, ex. in case no `*.cpp` files exists you will get `VAR="*.cpp"$'\n'`. Also note that your method adds a trailing newline on the end. I propose, just use `find`:

```
VAR=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.cpp')
```

You could also do:

```
VAR=$(printf "%s\n" *.cpp)
```

To fix the problem of no `*.cpp` files you could check if the file really exists:

```
for myfile in *.cpp; do
     if [ -e "$myfile" ]; then VAR+="$myfile"$'\n'; fi
done
```